# deleting an element in simply chained list C++

Tags: c++

so... I tried to make a delete function that deletes a string element, which I read from the kb. If I write the correct word, it works perfectly, but when I write an incorrect word it throws an error, Im not sure why...

```
void deleteword()
{
    system("CLS");
    cuvant* toDelete;
    cuvant* aux = primul;
    string desters;

    cout << "insert the word u want to delete: " << endl;
    cin >> desters;

    if(aux -> word == desters)
    {
        toDelete = aux;
//primul shows to the first element in the chained list
        primul = primul -> next;

        delete toDelete;
        return;
    }
    
    else
    {
        while(aux -> next -> word != desters)
        {
            if(aux -> next == NULL) break;
            aux = aux -> next;
        }

        if(aux -> next == NULL)
        {
            cout << "word wasn't found." << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {

        toDelete = aux -> next;
        aux -> next = aux -> next -> next;
        delete toDelete;

    return;
        }
    }




}
```

This is the subprogram with the problem, if u need the whole program, I can add it.

Comment: "it throws an error" - what kind of error?

Comment: Doing `if(aux -> next == NULL) ` *after* you have dereferenced `aux -> next` is not good.

Comment: Did you try to use your debugger?

Comment: it just ends the program, when it had to end the subprogram

Comment: You have also forgotten about the empty list. (This is usually a good first test case.)

Comment: tbh, Im not really sure what a debugger is.

Comment: thx, molbdnilo, Imma try to implement what ur saying

Comment: @Viktor291 a debugger is one of the most valuable tools for programmers, you should definitevely learn about it, it will save you a lot of time while programming. What is your platform/IDE/compiler/OS etc BTW?

Comment: umm.... basicly what I did was:
```while(aux -> next != NULL)
        {
            if(aux -> next -> word == desters) break;
            aux = aux -> next;
        }
```
changed the way the while function is written, and now works perfecly fine.
Thank you all for the helpu gave :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Im coding in CodeBlocks

Comment: thank you for the tip, I will check it out

Comment: @Viktor291 google ""codeblocks debugger", I'm sure you'll find tons of tutorials. Learning the basics of your debugger is well worth the investment of time

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you <3